# Keep checkbox array checked after submit-not working

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox, checked

I have refereed and tried many solutions provided in this type of question threads before asking my question as none of them working properly for me.
I have one mysql table of students which stores stud name, marks. 
I am retrieving that data from database using while loop.

```
$query="select * from student";
$rs=  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


<?php if(mysql_num_rows($rs)){ ?>
  <table border="5" cellspacing="5" width="50%" align="center">
      <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Marks</th>
          <th>Operation</th>
          <th>  <input type ="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></th>
      </tr>
      <?php


 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
          {


?>
      <tr>
           <th><?php echo $row['rollno']; ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $row['name']; ?></th>
          <th><?php echo $row['marks']; ?></th>
                      <th><a href="AllOperation.php?&no=<?php echo $row['rollno']; ?>&name=<?php echo $row['name']; ?>&marks=<?php echo $row['marks']; ?>">View</a></th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['marks']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['check']))  if (in_array($row['marks'], $_POST['check'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php  } ?>
<input type ="submit" name="total" value="total">
```

And i am generating the total of marks of all the students

```
if(isset($_POST['total']))


{                        $t=0;
                     foreach($_REQUEST['check'] as $val)
                     {                             
                         $t=$t+$val;                             
                     }
               echo "    total : ".$t;


 }
```

Now problem is that when first time i run the program it displays 5 student's information and than i selected first two checkbox and press the "total" button to generate the total. So it displays the total properly and keep that two check boxes checked. 
But when i checked third checkbox and press the "total" button than **it shows the total of that three selected check box's marks but it display 4th or last checkbox checked even if i did't checked it.** So why that is happening.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You need to understand how checkboxes work. Only checkboxes that are checked will actually be posted. If you have a name like `check[]` (which means that they will be posted as an array), and even if you have checked the third and the last, you will get an array containing only two elements (with index 0 and 1). It doesn't tell you in which position those checkboxes were in the form.

Comment: Another issue is that you use `isset($_POST['check'])` on every row, which only tells you if _any_ checkbox is checked, not if that _specific_ checkbox was checked.

Comment: I think, it is not matter, @MagnusEriksson. `if(isset($_POST['check']))` means: IF there are any checkbox which checked THEN ....
And `in_array($row['marks'], $_POST['check'])` will check value of `$_POST['check']`, index is not a problem.

Comment: @blueqn - That's my point. If you want to mark a row as checked, you don't care if _any_ is checked, you only care about if _that specific_ is checked. Otherwise, how would you determine which to check and which not to check?

Comment: @Dip, I think you should use a unique column as `rollno` rather than `marks`.
In case you need `marks` value, you can try:
`<th><input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $row['rollno']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['marks']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['check']) and isset($_POST['check'][$row['rollno']])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I think the first `if(isset($_POST['check'])` is the condition for second `if` command, which choose *specific* checkbox.

Comment: @blueqn - But the second if statement doesn't check for that specific checkbox. The code basically just checks if the rows value have been posted and looking at the table, there are multiple rows with the same values. That's a bad check since it will check _all_ rows containing that value instead of just the checked one. It's better to check if that specific checkbox was posted.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I agree with you. `marks` is not an identity column, should not use it to identify checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem I see:** `if (in_array($row['marks'], $_POST['check']) echo "checked='checked'`

When you submit, it always checks the checkboxs has the same marks

I think you should use another unique column, ex **$row['rollno'];** instead of **$row['marks']**